# Flowchart: Sort Two Numbers

Tags: sorting, flowchart

OBJECTIVE: Sort Two Numbers

```
Practice using basic flowchart symbols correctly;
    Start/Stop
    Output
    Input
    Process
    Decision
Use simple variables.
Specify an algorithm to solve a problem.
```

I've been trying to figure what to put in the process box to have it sort two numbers thats my main problem.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this.. You can add a condtion for the equal value.. or you can modify this if you want to have more inputs

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To sort numbers, we must compare them 2 at a time. If you have to sort only two numbers then you just have to compare them once by using >, <, >=, <=. Choose any one of these comparators, then proceed further by changing positions of the numbers according to the required order (ascending/descending). Tell me if I have missed something.

Comment: lets say I wanna sort 4 and 8 how would that look. Sorry for being so slow this question just keeps spawn camping me. I understand this is bubble sort I'm not sure why I'm not getting it

Comment: How do you want to sort (ascending/descending order)?

Comment: I'm assuming ascending order, let's take >= as the comparator. So first you compare 4 >= 8, which returns false, so no reordering. If the numbers are 12 & 8, then compare 12 >= 8, which returns true, so do reordering. And one more thing, store the numbers in an array, it's easier to do sorting in an array. Like for the case of 12 & 8, take a0 = 12 and a1 = 8. To reorder the numbers, use a temp variable like this: temp = a0; a0 = a1; a1 = temp.

Comment: And finally print the array in order from a0 - a1.